# Does the Borland compiler fail when we try to compile a large data case?

Tags: c++

If yes... then which compiler is best for compiling them?

I'm using the Borland 5.5 version. It shows an error:

> fault violation: unable to write on memory

Comment: What counts as "a large data case"?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Compilers work on source files, not data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be it is trying to write to read-only memory. Try using the next higher version of Borland.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a place where a colleague (not myself) uses a Borland compiler on 386 vintage computers.

He often has problems with memory management and has to choose very carefully which drivers he loads in DOS.

So, I wonder if you're using older software on older equipment?

You *might* be running into a limitation of the equipment.

Describe your configuration as fully as possible.

Comment: i m using borland 5.5 version.. the equipments i m using are not old.. i think its only the software.. yes it shows an error .. "fault violation: unable to write on memory"

Comment: Well, as I said, it's a colleague using a Borland compiler, and a Pascal one at that. I don't think I've heard him complain about the error you describe, but I'll mention it when I see him.

Comment: @vaibhav: Borland C++ 5.5 - that's the version they gave away for free about ten years ago. That's _very_ ancient. This compiler has very serious deficiencies many of which very fixed in later versions. AFAIK, there are free editions of at least one later Borland C++ compiler. Search for Turbo C++. (Beware, though: incredibly ancient DOS versions of their compilers were called that, too.) Currently the best free C++ compilers you can get for Windows are GCC and VC++ Express. The latter comes with a nice IDE and tries to lure you into .NET. The former is pure command line.