# Is there any way to obtain antique versions of Borland's Turbo C++ compiler for free?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am looking for an old version of the Borland Turbo C++ compiler. However I have to get it in legal way. Has anyone heard something about discounts for such old compilers?

**[EDIT]**

I would like to publicize my old sources for educational purposes, however they will only compile on this old compiler. I want to show my blog readers what mistakes they should try to avoid while learning a new language.

So It would be great if anyone could download the sources and compile them on their own computer. Therefore, I hope that maybe after so many years, Borland would give these old versions to the public for free...

Comment: Thank goodness you're not another one of those people trying to learn C++ on ancient compilers...

Comment: @Cody Gray: no, however this compiler become very important part of my programming soul... It would be great to have legal version of it :)

Comment: I completely understand the appeal of vintage computing! I have quite a collection of vintage computers myself, but I honestly wouldn't wish Turbo C++ on anyone.

Comment: Man - wish I could part with my boxed copy of Borland Turbo c++, version 1.0... If i could, I'd pass it along... but, can't let go ;(

Comment: See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438901/does-the-borland-compiler-fail-when-we-try-to-compile-a-large-data-case#comment1299043_1439015).

Comment: The official download place keeps moving around: It is now at [EDN → CodeCentral → C++Builder](http://cc.embarcadero.com/PopularDownloads.aspx?prodid=2). It includes [ID: 26014, Turbo C++ 1.01](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26014) (1991. 2.6 MB(!)) and [ID: 25636, Turbo C 2.01](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25636) (1989. 1 MB(!)). Though it seems to require registration in order to download.

Comment: Here is an account of downloading and using it in 2023 ([The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project)): *[Revisiting Borland Turbo C/C++, A Great IDE back in the 90s](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5358258/Revisiting-Borland-Turbo-C-Cplusplus-a-great-IDE-b)*. It should be possible to follow that and reproduce it.

Answer (score 17):

Embarcadero, the company that now owns Borland's developer tools, gives away a lot of their antique software for free. Turbo Pascal 1.0, 3.02, and 5.5 are available, as are Turbo C 2.01 and Turbo C++ 1.01.

You can [download the offerings here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/antiquesoftware) (the page is extremely slow, but it will load eventually).

And thanks to Alain Pannetier, who informs us that a slightly newer version, Turbo C++ 5.5, is also [available as a free download](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/c_builder).

---

But uh, if you're just looking for a freely downloadable C++ compiler, there are *much* better options, no time machine required. Check into [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and/or [Microsoft Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).

Comment: I am tempted to go and play with Turbo Pascal. I am sure I have some old programs around somwhere [definately not in source control tho]

Comment: probably this is what I was looking for, I will accept your answer if there will not be any compilation issues ;)

Comment: I dowloaded C++ 5.5 it last week from 'https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/c_builder' (last item).  @Cody Gray:  Yet another one ;-)

Comment: @Alain: I was going to add that to my answer, but then I noticed it was on a page titled "Free Trials". Are you sure that's not a time-limited free trial?

Comment: @Alain: But the C++ 5.5 free download includes only the compiler, no IDE,  doesn't it?

Comment: @Cody Gray. Positive. @harper.  Yes, there is no IDE, just plain bcc32, bcr32, ilink32, make etc...  That's why it's free.  It's not C++ builder.

Comment: @Cody Gray: my old creepy programs works only on old borland compiler. I would like to show my readers, that if something compiles and even seem to works, doesn't mean that this is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about Pascal or C? There are freeware equivalents that I've used to compile ancient [Turbo Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal) projects without a problem (FPK Pascal is one).

Ah, I miss Pascal. And [quiche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiche).

Comment: What is FPK Pascal? Do you mean [FPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal) Pascal?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links for sites that sell old Borland software:

http://www.recycledsoftware.com/servlet/the-BORLAND-C-pls--pls-/Categories

*[Old, Used and Out-of-Print
Borland®/Inprise® Software](http://www.emsps.com/oldtools/borland.htm)*

P.S. Why can't you compile the code with a newer compiler? Is it the C++ language
or the libraries you are using?

Comment: The first link is broken (404). Likely due to the domain having been taken over by somebody else.

Comment: For the last link: This is not for download, but presumably the original media (floppies?) for sale: *"The following old software development tools are in stock for sale or trade by EMS Professional Software."*. For example, ***"Turbo C 1.0. only. 5.25 diskettes. $79. Two in stock."***