# How to compile programs using Borland C++ Compiler v5.5 (bcc32)

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I just installed Borland C++ Compiler v5.5..

Where do I begin?
How do I compile C++ programs with it?

Comment: **By downloading a newer compiler.** Try [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Microsoft Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP). Why are you trying to use a compiler that is over 10 years old? I certainly hope you didn't miss the disclaimer [on my recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193635/is-there-any-way-to-obtain-antique-versions-of-borlands-turbo-c-compiler-for-f/5193792#5193792) concerning ancient Borland compilers...

Comment: And if learning C/C++ is what matters to you, get Code::Blocks with MinGW bundle. Open IDE, code and run. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

Check these articles:

http://edmulroy.portbridge.com/howto.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/usingbcc.aspx

P.S. I agree with the comments, that if you want to learn C++, it will be easier to start with a free C++ IDE like Visual C++ Express.

Answer (score 0):

Go to start, click on run, and type "Command", and hit enter.
Now, type "cd c:\borland\bcc55\bin" and hit enter.
You should be in the above directory now (your prompt should read: "c:\Borland\BCC55\Bin"); if not, check that you typed it correctly.
Type in "bcc32 test.cpp" and hit enter. This should result in the following output if everything worked: